# Rolling correlation and average (last 3) Per Group in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = [["ID1", 1, 5], ["ID1", 2, 6], ["ID1", 3, 7],
    ["ID1", 4, 4], ["ID1", 5, 2], ["ID1", 6, 2],
    ["ID2", 1, 4], ["ID2", 2, 6], ["ID2", 3, 1], 
    ["ID2", 4, 1], ["ID2", 5, 4]]
data = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=["ID", "colA", "colB"])
data

    ID      colA    colB
0   ID1     1       5
1   ID1     2       6
2   ID1     3       7
3   ID1     4       4
4   ID1     5       2
5   ID1     6       2
6   ID2     1       4
7   ID2     2       6
8   ID2     3       1
9   ID2     4       1
10  ID2     5       4
```

I want to calculate average and correlation of last 3 items, within each group.

However my dataset is very huge (>10Mn)

For average, I am trying like this, however it works on small data and chokes on actual data

```
data['Avg_last3'] = data.groupby(['ID'])['colB'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3).mean())
```

Correlation is between `colA` and `colB`. Average is only for `colB`

My final expected output is

```
    ID      colA    colB    Corr_last3  Avg_last3
0   ID1     1       5       0           5
1   ID1     2       6       1           5.5
2   ID1     3       7       1           6
3   ID1     4       4       -0.65       5.66
4   ID1     5       2       -0.99       4.33
5   ID1     6       2       -0.86       2.66
6   ID2     1       4       0           4
7   ID2     2       6       1           5
8   ID2     3       1       -0.59       3.66
9   ID2     4       1       -0.86       2.66
10  ID2     5       4       0.86        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
data['Avg_last3'] = data.groupby(['ID'])['colB'].rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3).mean().reset_index(drop=True)

data['Corr_last3'] = data.groupby(['ID'])['colB', 'colA'].rolling(min_periods = 1, window = 3).corr().iloc[0::2, -1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```py
     ID  colA  colB  Avg_last3  Corr_last3
0   ID1     1     5   5.000000         NaN
1   ID1     2     6   5.500000    1.000000
2   ID1     3     7   6.000000    1.000000
3   ID1     4     4   5.666667   -0.654654
4   ID1     5     2   4.333333   -0.993399
5   ID1     6     2   2.666667   -0.866025
6   ID2     1     4   4.000000         NaN
7   ID2     2     6   5.000000    1.000000
8   ID2     3     1   3.666667   -0.596040
9   ID2     4     1   2.666667   -0.866025
10  ID2     5     4   2.000000    0.866025
```

Comment: Correct, you don't need to group by here.

Comment: but the requirement is per group, it is different for ID1, ID2

Comment: the solution is very slow on 10Mn records, can we optimize it more?

Comment: Let me think about it. I dare say optimization here would have to come out of the box. I think in terms of pandas tooling - that's most we can do. Can you provide code to simulate this 10Mn using ```random```?